# Is there a way to calculate wind speed based on the horizontal movement or force of a falling object at one instant?

Tags: forces

Say I have the mass of an object, and the speed of its horizontal movement (and some other information, please continue reading), is there a way of calculating (horizontal) wind speed based on these things?

Just for clarification: `The horizontal movement of the object is 2 m/s, the vertical movement is 14m/s and the mass of the object is 0.3 kg, and assume that the forces aren't changing and that the speed isn't changing.`

I felt like it was wrong to assume that wind speed = lateral speed, so I calculated the horizontal force for my object: 0.754 newtons, so `assume the horizontal force of the unknown wind speed against the object is equal to 0.754 newtons and that the vertical force is 9.81*0.3 = 2.943 Newtons, ignoring air resistance (for vertical force))`. But I have no idea how to convert this into wind speed because nothing feels quite right.

I was also thinking about using the mass flow rate of the wind hitting against the surface area of the side of the falling object `(v(wind) * rho * A)`. If this is the correct way of solving this problem, assume that the side area of the object is 0.0336 m^2.

Please tell me how to calculate the wind speed, it feels like I'm overcomplicating the problem but nothing I'm trying feels quite right.

Underneath is a picture summarizing all the information (remember that the speeds and the forces aren't changing):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object is moving at a constant horizontal speed, its speed equals the windspeed. Consider a balloon floating through the air - if it is moving slower than the wind, the wind will accelerate it. If it is moving faster than the wind, from the balloon's reference, it's a wind pointing in the opposite direction, so the balloon will slow down. The only time the balloon isn't being sped up or slowed by the wind is when it is moving at the same speed as the wind.

There is only one force that can accelerate the balloon horizontally, and that's drag from the wind passing over/around it. If the balloon isn't accelerating, the net force on it must be zero, so the drag must be zero. This only occurs when there is no relative movement between the air and the balloon, i.e., when the balloon's speed matches the windspeed.

If the balloon isn't moving at a constant speed, you could estimate windspeed from the acceleration of the balloon, although that will be somewhat more complicated as the drag force will constantly be changing with the relative speed between the air the balloon.

Comment: So the answer was that simple after all, I guess my brain just thinks of every option that isn't the correct one.